# Get the id of the selected value in combobox with Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I want to get the Id of the selected index in my combobox in knockout is it possible ?

```
<select id="lstEntreprisesCbx" data-bind="options:Entreprises,
                        optionsText: 'NomEntreprise',
                        optionsCaption: '-- Nouvelle Entreprise --'">
</select>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `selectedIndex` property of the select element to find out the currently selected option.

If you wanted to put this in a binding handler, you could something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.selectedIndex = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function() {
             var value = valueAccessor();
            if (ko.isWriteableObservable(value)) {
               value(element.selectedIndex);   
            }
        });
    }
};
```

This assumes that you are binding it against an observable (if you want to bind against a non-observable, then it takes a little more code) and you would use it like:

```
<select id="lstEntreprisesCbx" data-bind="options:Entreprises,
                        optionsText: 'NomEntreprise',
                        optionsCaption: '-- Nouvelle Entreprise --',
                        selectedIndex: myIndex">
</select>
```

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/K6SZQ/

## update

I had read the question as specifically wanting the `selectedIndex` of the currently selected value, which may have been wrong.  If you really want to get something like an `id` of the currently selected object, then you can use the `value` binding along with the `optionsValue` option.  It would look like:

```
<select id="lstEntreprisesCbx" data-bind="options:Entreprises,
                        optionsText: 'NomEntreprise',
                        optionsCaption: '-- Nouvelle Entreprise --',
                        value: selectedId,
                        optionsValue: 'id'">
</select>
```

So, you specify which value to update in the `value` binding and which property to use (as a string) in the `optionsValue` binding.  If you omit `optionsValue`, then it will populate your `value` with the entire object.  This is also what you would use if your options array was just primitive values.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/3LyLs/

Comment: Why not just use the `value` binding? Am I missing something here?

Comment: I guess that I thought he specifically wanted the `selectedIndex` of the item.  Re-reading the question though, maybe that is not necessarily true. Will update the response.